# Convert decimal number to INT SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, decimal, number-formatting

I want to convert the decimal number 3562.45 to 356245, either as an `int` or a `varchar`. I am using `cast(3562.45 as int)`, but it only returns 3562. How do I do it?

Comment: `select cast(3562.45 * 100 as int)`

Comment: This sounds not like a conversion to me, the number 356245 is not a conversion of 3562.45, it's a different number. A conversion of 3562.45 into int would be 3562 or 3563, depending on the rule of conversion one would choose.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Or you can replace the decimal point.

```
select cast(replace('3562.45', '.','') as integer)
```

This way, it doesn't matter how many decimal places you have.

Answer (score 22):

How about the obvious:

```
CAST(3562.45*100 as INTEGER)
```

Answer (score 13):

This works for me

```
SELECT FLOOR(55.5999)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use also the [CONVERT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp) function:

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, 3562.45 * 100)
```